# How to use the BLoC library?

Tags: flutter, dart

I'm trying to figure out the BLoC library, but it gives me headaches.

I'm trying to fetch hotel names from an API. I have a model and a service responsible for contacting the API and fetching the data. However, I don't know how to connect it to the BLoC library.

Once my app starts, I want BLoC to fetch the data from the API and then show it in the app.

Here's my code:

### hotel_model.dart

```dart
class Hotels {
  final List<Hotel> hotels;

  Hotels({this.hotels});

  factory Hotels.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) {
    return Hotels(
      hotels: List<Hotel>.from(
        json['hotels'].map(
          (x) => Hotel.fromJson(x),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}

class Hotel {
  final String hotelName;

  Hotel({this.hotelName});

  factory Hotel.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) {
    return Hotel(
      hotelName: json['name'],
    );
  }
}
```

### hotel_service.dart

```dart
import 'package:http/http.dart' as http;

abstract class DownloadService {
  Future<http.Response> fetchHotels();
}

class HotelService extends DownloadService {
  @override
  Future<http.Response> fetchHotels() {
    final Uri uri = Uri.https('services.lastminute.com', 'mobile/stubs/hotels');

    return http.get(uri);
  }
}
```

And here's what I did wit the BLoC lib.

#### hotel_event.dart

```dart
part of 'hotel_bloc.dart';

@immutable
abstract class HotelEvent {}

class OnAppStartEvent extends HotelEvent {}
```

### hotel_bloc.dart

```dart
import 'dart:async';

import 'package:bloc/bloc.dart';
import 'package:hotels/models/hotel/hotel_model.dart';
import 'package:hotels/services/hotel/hotel_service.dart';
import 'package:meta/meta.dart';

part 'hotel_event.dart';
part 'hotel_state.dart';

class HotelBloc extends Bloc<HotelEvent, HotelState> {
  HotelBloc() : super(HotelFinal());

  final HotelService hotelService = HotelService();

  @override
  Stream<HotelState> mapEventToState(
    HotelEvent event,
  ) async* {
    if (event is FetchEvent) {
      final response = hotelService.fetchHotels();

      yield 
    }
  }
}
```

### hotel_state.dart

```dart
part of 'hotel_bloc.dart';

@immutable
abstract class HotelState {
  HotelState();
}

class HotelFinal extends HotelState {
  final Hotel hotel;
  HotelFinal(this.hotel);

  Hotel getHotel() {
    return hotel;
  }
}
```

Comment: Have a look at [Bloc Library](https://bloclibrary.dev/#/gettingstarted) to understand the basics

Comment: @quoci Yeah, i know the basics but there are a lot of outdated info there.

Comment: Put an await in  hotelService.fetchHotels();
After that you have all your hotels.now you want to yield those data in a state e.g. your HotelFinal -> yield HotelFinal(response)

Comment: I recommend you this [package](https://pub.dev/packages/equatable). It's pretty handy if you use blocs.

Answer (score 0):

1. First of all add `await` to this line in your bloc 
   `final response = await hotelService.fetchHotels();`
2. return `List<Hotel>` from your `fetchHotels` function
3. you must have `stateful` class for your screen and in the `initState`
   you can create your bloc object and call `.add` method on it
4. in your `build` method wrap your widget with `BlocBuilder` and on `builder` callback check your bloc state, if the state is `HotelFinal` return your ui with list of hotels in your state object.

Answer (score 0):

1. It'll be useful to add another state for your `HotelState` for when your bloc is fetching the data, and even for when there's an error. e.g;

```
part of 'hotel_bloc.dart';

@immutable
abstract class HotelState {
  HotelState();
}

class HotelFinal extends HotelState {
  final Hotel hotel;
  HotelFinal(this.hotel);

  Hotel getHotel() {
    return hotel;
  }
}

class HotelLoading extends HotelState {
  HotelLoading();
}

class HotelError extends HotelState {
  final String error;
  HotelError(this.error);
}
```

2. You would want to change your `mapEventToState` to something like this:

```
 @override
  Stream<HotelState> mapEventToState(
    HotelEvent event,
  ) async* {
    if (event is FetchEvent) {
      yield HotelLoading();
      try {
        final response = await hotelService.fetchHotels();
        // It seems like your service doesn't return an hotel directly, so you'll have to deal with this as it is not part of the question.
        final hotel = getYourHotelHereWithTheResponse;
        yield HotelFinal(hotel);
      } catch (e) {
        yield HotelError('something went wrong getting the hotel info');
      }
    }
   }
```

3. Lastly, add a widget to your widget tree that adds `FetchEvent` to your bloc and add a `BlocBuilder` to react to the change of states. Note that this is very flexible and can be done in many ways, but it is out of the scope of your very broad question, I'm just showing you how to use the library at a minimal:

```
class MyStatefulWidget extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _MyStatefulWidgetState createState() => _MyStatefulWidgetState();
}

class _MyStatefulWidgetState extends State<MyStatefulWidget> {

  HotelBloc hotelBloc;

  @override
  void initState() {
    hotelBloc = HotelBloc..add(FetchEvent());
    super.initState();
  }

  @override
  void dispose() {
    hotelBloc.close();
    super.dispose();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return BlocBuilder(builder: (context, state) {
      if(state is HotelLoading) {
        // return a widget to deal with loading
      }
      
      if(state is HotelFinal) {
        // return a widget to deal with success
      }
      
      if(state is HotelError) {
        // return a widget to deal with error
      }
    });
  }
}
```